# Stack level too deep on user.save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to assign a confirmation code to my users while creating one. And I also titleize some columns before saving-updating them. So my user.rb looks like this (it may be a bit messy):

```
// user.rb
*** some code ***
before_save { titleize_column(:name)
                titleize_column(:surname)
                capitalize_column(:complaints) 
                capitalize_column(:education)
                capitalize_column(:job)
                capitalize_column(:complaintsdetails)
                capitalize_column(:prediagnosis)
                capitalize_column(:existingdiagnosis)
                capitalize_column(:knownilnessesother)
                capitalize_column(:usedmedicine)
                capitalize_column(:operation)
                capitalize_column(:trauma)
                capitalize_column(:allergy)
                capitalize_column(:otherhabits)
                capitalize_column(:motherother)
                capitalize_column(:fatherother)
                capitalize_column(:siblingsother)
              }
  before_save :generate_confirmation_code
protected
    def generate_confirmation_code
      unless self[:confirmed]
        if(self[:type] == 'Patient')
          update_attribute :confirmation_code, SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(20)
          update_attribute :confirmed, false
        else
          update_attribute :confirmed, true
        end
      end
    end

protected
    def capitalize_column(attr)
      unless self[attr].nil?
        self[attr] = Unicode::capitalize self[attr]
      end
    end

  protected
    def titleize_column(attr)
      unless self[attr].nil?
        words = self[attr].split
        words.each_with_index do |v,i|
          words[i] = Unicode::capitalize v
        end
        self[attr] = words.join(" ")
      end
    end
```

I'm using separate methods for titleizing and capitalizing columns because they may be nil when first creating a user, so I'm checking if it is null or not in those methods. This structure works fine on a normal signup with strong parameters. However, if I try to use twitter signup with the method below, it gives me the error 'stack level too deep' and I can see that it calls the `generate_confirmation_code` 123 times from the application trace and then these happens:

**app/models/user.rb:83:in `each'
app/models/user.rb:83:in`each_with_index'
app/models/user.rb:83:in `titleize_column'
app/models/user.rb:20:in`block in '
app/models/user.rb:64:in `generate_confirmation_code' (x123 times)
app/models/user.rb:101:in`from_omniauth'
app/controllers/socials_controller.rb:4:in `create'**

```
// method for signing up/logging in a user from twitter

  class << self
    def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
      if exists?(uid: auth_hash['uid'])
        user = find_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'])
      else
        user = find_or_create_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'], type: 'Patient')
        user.password_digest = User.digest('111111')
        user.name = auth_hash['info']['name']
        user.location = get_social_location_for user.provider, auth_hash['info']['location']
        user.avatar = auth_hash['info']['image']
        user.url = get_social_url_for user.provider, auth_hash['info']['urls']
        user.save!            // THIS IS THE LINE 101!
        conversation = Conversation.create()
        user.conversation = conversation
        admin = Admin.first
        admin.conversations << conversation
        user.progress = Progress.create(active_state:1)
      end
      user
    end
```

I think I'm messing up by using before_save not properly, but do not know how to do it right. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`update_attribute` also fires the `save` callbacks, thereby looping the `before_save` infinitely, thus producing stack level too deep.

You can just simply assign values in a `before_save` callback methods, because they will simply be saved afterwards anyway. See the following:

```
def generate_confirmation_code
  unless self[:confirmed]
    if(self[:type] == 'Patient')
      self.confirmation_code = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(20)
      self.confirmed = false
    else
      self.confirmed = true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `update_attribute` inside `before_save` callback method, instead you can just assign values to attributes. The method signature `generate_confirmation_code` should be like below -

```
def generate_confirmation_code
  unless self[:confirmed]
    if(self[:type] == 'Patient')
      self.confirmation_code = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(20)
      self.confirmed = false
    else
      self.confirmed = true
    end
  end
end
```